# Error message when creating django project

Tags: python, django, windows

I'm just starting learn django and trying to create a blog locally using django cms (for information I'm using Windows 7). But when I tried to create a new project from command prompt like this:

```
django-admin.py startproject mysite
```

I'm getting an error:

> 'django-admin.py' is not recognized as an internal or externaal
>   command, operable program or batch file.

I've installed django before, and tested it in python command line:

```
import django
print(django.get_version());
```

and return

```
1.7.1
```

This is my first project. Can anyone tell me "Why I can't create a new project?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The situation is described in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/):

> The django-admin script should be on your system path if you installed
>   Django via its setup.py utility. If it’s not on your path, you can
>   find it in site-packages/django/bin within your Python installation.
>   Consider symlinking it from some place on your path, such as
>   /usr/local/bin.
>
> For Windows users, who do not have symlinking functionality available,
>   you can copy django-admin.exe to a location on your existing path or
>   edit the PATH settings (under Settings - Control Panel - System -
>   Advanced - Environment...) to point to its installed location.

In other words, either place `django-admin.exe` somewhere under an existing path in `PATH`, or add `site-packages/django/bin` to the `PATH`.

Comment: my `django-admin.exe` installed under `C:\Python34\Scripts`. What should I do with that?

Comment: @agus-putra-dana add `C:\Python34\Scripts` to the `PATH` environment variable. Should do the trick.

Comment: thanks for your help. I just forgot that the file is not `.py` but `.exe`.